# moving a used refrigerator

Tags: appliances, refrigerator

I bought a used refrigerator from a used appliance store.  It was running when purchased, unplugged, and loaded upright onto the truck and has been that way since Friday.  Once it is brought inside the house, does it need to sit for a time before plugging in?

Answer (score 4):

As it was never on its side, you should be able to use it without waiting.

If it was laid on its side, the manuals tend to say leave it upright for 24 hours before plugging it in.

Comment: I agree, when fridges are laid down the oil in the system migrates out of the compressor an can cause compressor failure, it can also plug capillary tubes. As long as it is moved upright no wait time is needed.+